# Finding all integers $a$ so that $(x^2 + 2a )(x-2)(x-4) + 2$ has all real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Consider the polynomial $(x^2 + 2a )(x-2)(x-4) + 2$ , $a \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> I need to find the values of $a$ for which this polynomial has all real roots.

I have reduced the case for $a < 5$, but for rest of the cases is there a quick way to check if polynomial has all real roots other than usual way of plugging the values?

Any help??

Comment: The location of roots is a continuous function of the coefficients (in fact, a smooth function when the roots are simple). You should look for $a$ where the polynomial has double root (or equivalent, the polynomial and its derivative has common roots), it will give you the boundary of those $a$ where the number of real roots (counting multiplicity) changes.

Comment: It seems that the polynomial is positive for $ x\ge 4$ and for $x\le 2.$ So the roots must squeeze in $(2,4).$

Comment: The sum of the roots is equal $6.$ If all of them are real, then the sum is at least $8,$ as each root must be greater than $2.$

Comment: The title says integers but the body says $a$ is a natural number, which can only be positive integers. Which is it?